# Office365 Excel and different formatting inside cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, formatting

LibreOffice can do different formatting inside cell. But when I try to do the same with Excel on Office365 it does not work.

e.g. I have text:

[image]

When I select part to format it, bold/italic/underline/etc buttons are disabled:

[image]

I cannot check it on desktop Excel, but I believe it allows it (similarly as LibreOffice). What's wrong? Do I need to upgrade / pay? Or just not implemented for web?

Comment: OpenOffice can do it too, but I don't think Microsoft Excel can do it. However, I believe if you load the document made in OpenOffice, it is still working in excel, but I could be wrong there.

Comment: What happens if you select the word "bar" not in the formula bar, but directly in the cell? Will bold/italic/underline/etc buttons be disabled then?

Comment: Could you please go to File > Account > Product Information, check the version number ? On my test environment with Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise install, I can choose the part of content in formual bar to set style.

Comment: Formatting part of a a text string works on the desktop version but not on the web based  app (and this remains true even if you are a Microsoft 365 subscriber).

Comment: @JohnSUN Selecting directly in the cell does not work either (obviously, I'd be really surprised if it worked).

Comment: @Emily Build: `16.0.14931.37953` (is that wat you want?). But I guess @DMM is right.